# Adding to sources.list

Tags: debian, apt

I want to do an apt-get install on the library located here:

https://packages.debian.org/testing/libdevel/liblmdb-dev

what do I add to the sources.list file?

I can't find a good resource that explains how to do this.

I tried something like this:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

but, thats not working.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your current `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

This line has to be in /etc/apt/sources.list.

If you are using debian testing, then `apt-get update` and `apt-get install yourthing`

Else create the file /etc/apt/apt.conf and type `APT::Default-Release "stable";` (if you are using debian stable) then `apt-get update` and `apt-get -t testing install yourthing`